# Can we apply the definition of atoms to partitions and not just $\sigma$-fields?

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

I am reading the following paper

> Beloso-Herves, C. and Monteiro, P.K. Information and s-algebras.
> *Economic Theory*, 54(2): 405-418, 2013.

which relies on the following definition of a partition

**Partitions of $S$**: $S_{\tau}\subset 2^{S}\backslash \{\emptyset\}$ is a partition of $S$ if

- $S:=\cup\left\{A\subseteq S:A\in S_{\tau}\right\}$
- $A_{1},A_{2}\in S_{\tau}$ and $A_{1}\not =A_{2}$ imply $A_{1}\cap A_{2}=\emptyset$.

In the paper they refer to an atom of $S_{\tau}$ which troubles me because my understanding of atoms is they typically apply to $\sigma$-fields $\mathscr{S}$ of subsets of $S$, presumably because the definition requires $\emptyset\in\mathscr{S}$? For partitions the empty set is excluded. Thus is there another definition of atoms that apply to classes where the empty set does not have to be a member? Unfortunately the authors do not elaborate on their definitions of atoms.

---

UPDATE: adding in definition of atoms

**Atoms of a $\sigma$-field**: If $\mathscr{S}$ is a $\sigma$-field of subsets of $S$, a set $\text{atom}(\mathscr{S})\in\mathscr{S}$ is an atom of $\mathscr{S}$, if for all $B\in\mathscr{S}$ satisfying $B\subseteq \text{atom}(\mathscr{S})$, $B=\emptyset$ or $B=\text{atom}(\mathscr{S})$

---

UPDATE: Adding some context

The authors define $f:S\longrightarrow T$ to be a signal onto $T$ (I take this as simply being an onto mapping from $S$ to $T$). The space $T$ is left unspecified.

Suppose $S_{\tau}$ is an arbitrary partition of $S$. They define the following equivalence relation on $S_{\tau}$

$$s\sim_{\tau}t\Longleftrightarrow \text{atom}(s,S_{\tau})= \text{atom}(t,S_{\tau})$$

Let $S_{\sim_{\tau}}=\{[s]_{\sim_{\tau}}:s\in S\}$ be the quotient set. Define

\begin{align}
f:S\longrightarrow S_{\sim_{\tau}}\\
f(s)\mapsto \text{atom}(t,S_{\tau})
\end{align}

They then go to claim $\tau_{f}:=\{f^{-1}([s]_{\sim_{\tau}}):[s]_{\sim_{\tau}}\in S_{\sim_{\tau}}\}=S_{\tau}$

**My question arises from the definition of $f$ which clearly suggests $S_{\tau}$ can have an atom?**

I have asked a question recently [inverse images versus inverse functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4842956/inverse-images-of-sets-versus-inverse-functions-should-we-use-different-notati)about $f^{-1}$ and show there some working convincing myself the claim is true.

Comment: I have never seen "atom of a partition". It may be an element that's a singleton. If you [edit] the question to show us the context (perhaps a paragraph) where the phrase appears we may be able to help.

Comment: Thanks for your interest @EthanBolker I have added in some context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* this is just the standard argument that partitions and equivalence relations are essentially the same. If I am right then the author is using "atom of a partition" where mathematicians say "block of a partition". Then $\text{atom}(s,S_\tau)$ is just the block of the partition that contains $s$. Then two elements of $S$ are equivalent just when they are in the same block.

Partitions never contain an empty block. This definition of "atom" does not cause them. Every block has something in it.

I think that the rest of the passage is the standard argument that surjections (that is, onto mappings) are also essentially the same as partitions and equivalence relations.

This is all explained on the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation)  for equivalence relations.

Comment: Thank you Ethan. Firstly did you mean $\text{atom}(s,S_{\tau})$ rather than $\text{atom}(s,S+\tau)$? I thought however that $\emptyset\not\in S_{\tau}$ since partitions contain only non-empty sets, and the definition of atoms (I use anyway) requires $\emptyset\in S_{\tau}$ to be possible?

Comment: Fixed typo and added some text.

Comment: Thanks! I suppose then whilst $\emptyset\in S_{\tau}$ is suggested by the definition of atoms, knowing precisely what $S_{\tau}$ is tells us this is not possible (in contrast to $\sigma$-fields for instance). Thus $B\subset \text{atom}(s,S_{\tau})$ for some $B\in S_{\tau}$ only leads to one possibility, that is $B=\text{atom}(s,S_{\tau})$.